# duplicate date by every row nav 2009

Tags: navision

I have a GetDates function like this:

```
GetDates(BOM : Record "BOM Component";VAR StartDate : Date;VAR EndDate : Date)
// Called from OnAfterGetRecord in form 36

IF BOM.GET("Parent Item No.",BOM."Line No.") THEN BEGIN
  //MESSAGE(FORMAT(BeginDate));
  StartDate := BeginDate;
  EndDate := EndDate;
END
```

And I hava a from 36 where I call the function:

```
//ItemAdditionBeginDate := 0D;
ItemAdditionBeginDate := ItemAdditionHallo.BeginDate;
//ItemAdditionEndDate := 0D;
ItemAdditionEndDate := ItemAdditionHallo.EndDate;

ItemAddition.GetDates(Rec,ItemAdditionBeginDate,ItemAdditionEndDate);
ItemAddition.GetRegelkorting(salesLine, ItemAddition.Regelkorting);
```

But the problem is dat every time you add a new date in the form it copies the value to the other row, like this:

[image]

So how to solve that the dates are not been copied.

Thank you

I declare getDates in TABLE 50012:

```
GetDates(BOM : Record "BOM Component";VAR StartDate : Date;VAR EndDate : Date)
// Called from OnAfterGetRecord in form 36

IF BOM.GET("Parent Item No.",BOM."Line No.") THEN BEGIN
  //MESSAGE(FORMAT(BeginDate));
  StartDate := BeginDate;
  EndDate := EndDate;
END
```

And this is for setDates:

```
SetDates(BOM : Record "BOM Component";VAR StartDate : Date;VAR EndDate : Date)
// Called from OnValidate of start and end dates in form 36
BOM.INIT;
"Item No." := BOM."Line No.";
"Parent Item No." := BOM."Parent Item No.";
//Stuklijst."Line No." := BOM."Line No.";
StartDate := StartDate;
EndDate := EndDate;


IF NOT MODIFY THEN 
  INSERT;
```

[image]

oke, I have it now like this:

```
SetDates(BOM : Record "BOM Component";VAR startDateparm : Date;VAR EndDateparam : Date)
// OnValidate of start and end dates in form 36

BOM.INIT;
"Item No."             := BOM."Line No.";
"Parent Item No."      := BOM."Parent Item No.";
BeginDate              := startDateparm;
EndDate                := EndDateparam;

IF NOT MODIFY THEN 
  INSERT;
```

but the dates are still copying from the previous record. If I go to a other record:

See image:
[image]

Comment: Hello, in function `GetDates()` you pass two parameters type date `StartDate` and `EndDate`. Then you assign values, `StartDate := BeginDate`; and `EndDate := EndDate`, the question is: When you assign a value for `BeginDate`? and `EndDate` Assigned its own value? In which object is define the function `GetDates()`.

Comment: After to call `SetDates()` function if you use the debugger the values for `StartDate` and `EndDate` are corrects? you can change de name of this params (StartDate and EndDate)? because they have the same name as the fields of the table.

Comment: yes, they are correct

Comment: Ok, I perform some test and the problem must be in the assignament of `StartDate := StartDate` and `EndDate := EndDate` Please put the debugger in line `IF NOT MODIFY THEN` and cheque the values of the table that you can MODiFY or INSERT. Let me know please.

Comment: I edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for answer my questions about your process. Check the last image. you are inserting or modifying the BOM table.

This is your code:

```
SetDates(BOM : Record "BOM Component";VAR StartDate : Date;VAR EndDate : Date)

// Called from OnValidate of start and end dates in form 36
BOM.INIT;
"Item No." := BOM."Line No.";
"Parent Item No." := BOM."Parent Item No.";
//Stuklijst."Line No." := BOM."Line No.";
StartDate := StartDate;
EndDate := EndDate;

IF NOT MODIFY THEN 
  INSERT;
```

If you check the las image you can see the parameters `StartDate` and `EndDate` are correct, but when you assign this values to BOM table fields (`StartDate, EndDate`) the values are in blank.
This happend because your parameters have the same **name** as the fields the **BOM table**

Change your code for this:

```
SetDates(BOM : Record "BOM Component";VAR parmStartDate : Date;VAR parmEndDate : Date)
//Declare new variable of BOM table, recBOM - record - BOM
// Called from OnValidate of start and end dates in form 36
recBOM.INIT;
recBOM."Item No."             := BOM."Line No.";
recBOM."Parent Item No."      := BOM."Parent Item No.";    
recBOM.StartDate              := parmStartDate;
recBOM.EndDate                := parmEndDate;

IF NOT recBOM.MODIFY THEN 
  recBOM.INSERT;
```

Comment: @Jonathan.Thank you. I will test it monday. I will let you now.

Comment: I edit the answer, check te last function, create a new variable recBOM and insert or modify this vatiable.